# Visual Studio Web Application edit source while running like in Tomcat\Eclipse\Java

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

In an ASP.NET Web Site project, I've always been able to make changes to the underlying C# code and simply refresh the page in the browser and my changes would be there instantly.

I can do the same thing when working with Java and Eclipse - edit my Java source and refresh the page and my changes are there.

I cannot do this in ASP.NET MVC though and it is a real downer - I have to stop the running process and make my changes, and then restart debugging.  This is a huge waste of time.

Am I doing it wrong? What is the best approach to ASP.NET MVC development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio locks the source code in debug mode. So your options are:

1. Publish the site on your local IIS and use the "attach to proccess".
2. Use Run without Debug (Ctrl-F5) instead and again "attach to proccess".
3. Break the execution in debug mode (with Breakpoint).

The first one is my favorite.

Comment: You can also "Pause" (Ctrl+Alt+Break), make your change, click "Continue" and refresh the page.

Answer (score 6):

I rarely use debug mode in ASP.NET MVC project (<kbd>F5</kbd>). I run the project once with <kbd>CTRL+F5</kbd> and always have a browser window open. Then if I make a change to a view (.aspx, .ascx), I hit <kbd>F5</kbd> in the browser and changes automatically take effect. If I have to do changes in the .NET code (controller logic, models, repositories, etc...) I no longer use the browser. To verify that my change is correct I navigate to the corresponding unit test and hit <kbd>CTRL+R+T</kbd>. The result is seen either in green or red.

Comment: This is one of the huge benefits of MVC. Why fire up the debugger when building, your tests should cover a majority of your logic. Same with webforms MVP. Save yourself a TON of time and start writing good tests.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to stop the process, you can break.

Try breaking the project, then editing, then continue.

1) CTRL-ALT-BREAK
2) Edit your code
3) F5

Answer (score 1):

My technique has been to launch it normally then copy the URL from the browser and open another window for the website then kill the original. Once you kill the original browser, VS lets your source code go but you still have it up in another window and can navigate it normally. Now you can edit your code and then refresh the browser and it works just like before.

The only reason to launch it normally first because VS seems to pick a random port number against localhost when firing up the built in IIS. But even that rarely changes

My URL usually looks something like this:

http://localhost:49434/something.apsx

The port numbe changes on occasion but it seems to stay the same as long as you dont close visual studio. Once you kill VS your URL will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Run the MVC project with shortcut key (CTRL + F5) and now any changes you make to the C# code would be reflected in browser after refreshing (F5)

Answer (score -1):

The fastest way to code is to Host locally on IIS and then all you have to do is build the solution before checking out your changes.

Another alternative is chucking everything into the App_Code folder which will compile on the fly as you make changes.